# openshift error: "pods "XXX" is forbidden: cpu max limit request ratio per Container is 40, but provided ratio is 160", resources change does nothing

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, openshift, replicaset

openshift ReplicaFailure "pods "XXX" is forbidden: cpu max limit request ratio per Container is 40, but provided ratio is 160" when trying to create a pod

I tried to change resources but with this deployment resources change does nothing, and even the provided ratio doesnt change (I tried in another deployments and it does make a change).
I also tried to delete all replica sets, and it didnt help...

deployment:

```
spec:   
    template:  
        spec:  
            containers:  
                - name: example  
                  resources:  
                      limits:  
                          cpu: '1'
                          memory: 2Gi
                      requests:  
                          cpu: '1'
                          memory: 2Gi
```

limitrange:

```
spec: 
    limits: 
        - type: Container 
          min: 
              cpu: 25m 
              memory: 200M
          default: 
              cpu: 100m 
              memory: 200M 
          defaultRequest: 
              cpu: 100m 
              memory: 200M 
          maxLimitRequestRatio: 
              cpu: '40'
              memory: '29'
```

Comment: do you have limitranges or resourcequotas defined in your namespace/cluster? `oc get limitranges  -A`  `oc get resourcequotas -A`

Comment: yes i have limitrange and  the max limit/request ratio is 160 (but i put in the deployment resources of cpu request 1 and cpu limit 1, so i dont break the ratio. another thing is that no metter what is put in the resoueces, it always writes "... but provided ratio is 160", other deployments affected by the change of resources but this one doesnt...) @titou10

Comment: could you share the limitrange manifest and also the deployment manifest?

Comment: deployment: - spec:   
    template:  
        spec:  
            containers:  
                - name: example  
                   resources:  
                        limits:  
                            cpu: '1'
                            memory: 2Gi
                        requests:  
                            cpu: '1'
                            memory: 2Gi @titou10

Comment: limitrange - spec: limits: -type: Container min: cpu: 25m memory: 200M default: cpu: 100m memory: 200M defaultRequest: cpu: 100m memory: 200M maxLimitRequestRatio: cpu: 40 memory: '29' @titou10 (sorry that it not printed so nicely)

Comment: lol. update your initial post with the manifests

Comment: lol,  I did it @titou10

Comment: "{...}yes i have limitrange and the max limit/request ratio is 160{...}" ? it's not what is defined in your limitrange here...do you have other active limitrange?